# Determine who clicked a link in an email

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So my company wants to do a small experiment and generate an email that'll be sent to about 50 workers. The email will include a link to a website (stored on our local server) and I need to be able to determine exactly who clicked the link (I have a list of all email addresses) and add the email address of the "victim" to another list. I think there's a way to do that with Node.js and Express but I'm not sure exactly how to track those clicks. Any ideas?

I'm aware that a script like that should come before the user enters the actual website and I can deal with most HTML, CSS and JS programming myself.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Uh, the actual thing should be simple - give each person a unique token in the URL and count those. But it seems you're asking for how to do everything to do with processing what happens after the click and after the request is made to the server which is probably too broad.

Comment: You can't reliably determine who clicked the link - it could be that someone had the email app opened but yet someone else clicked the link (wife, child, coworker). Which means that if you want to take some actions for/against people who clicked the link, this is never 100% accurate.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'd argue that having somebody open their work email, and then allowing somebody else to use it, is still actionable. Sure, it wasn't the worker that clicked it and maybe they really knew better to not do it, yet they are still responsible for preventing it, as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this somewhat fun "experiment" takes place in our office so I doubt their wife and kids will have access but I absolutely get the idea. I'll definitely try to generate their emails in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and I need to be able to determine exactly who clicked the link...

It depends.

- If you have some form of single-sign-on implemented across your intranet, then you can at least know what user account was signed in when they followed the link (which doesn't guarantee you what user it was, but people really shouldn't leave their workstations unattended and unlocked), assuming your Node.js application gets that information.
- Otherwise: You can't, reliably. What you **can** do is make the link slightly different for each recipient (perhaps a code at the end in the query string), keeping track of which code you sent to which recipient, and then when they follow the link look at the code in the link they followed.

  It's unreliable for at least a couple of reasons:

  - A user could remove the code
  - A user could share their link with other users, who then use it

  Similarly, trying to use the user's IP address or MAC address only tells you...what the IP address or MAC address of the connection was, not who the user was.

Comment: As TJ said do something like http://website/?email=victim@gmail.com

Comment: "*A user could remove the code*" this can be mitigated to some extent if the code is embedded inside the URL. E.g., `somesite.com/link/1234/user-friendly-name.html` that emulates having an ID and a user readable location (just like this question!) but `1234` is actually the unique token given to identify a user. It doesn't help against sharing links and it doesn't help if somebody decides to change that code anyway but it should be easier to pass off as normal, even to more tech-savvy people who might recognise that in `somesite.com?id=1234` the query string is not needed.